# Java ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, exception, classnotfoundexception

I did a search for this question and couldn't find a solution.

I am running a solution that I created for the popular KataPokerHands challenge. I have two classes `CardDeck` and `Dealer`, the dealer uses a card deck. When I run the program I get an error saying that the JVM cannot find the `CardDeck` class that is being invoked by the Dealer class, even though both classes exist in the same directory.

this is the cardeck class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CardDeck 
{
    private final ArrayList<String> deck;

    CardDeck() 
    {
        deck = new ArrayList<>();      
        for(int i = 2; i < 10; i++)
        {
            deck.add(i + "H");
            deck.add(i + "D");
            deck.add(i + "S");
            deck.add(i + "C");
        }

        deck.addAll(Arrays.asList("TH TD TS TC JH JD JS JC QH QD QS QC KH KD KS KC AH AD AS AC".split(" ")));
    }
    ArrayList<String> getDeck()
    {
        return deck;
    }
}
```

and this is the dealer class:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class Dealer 
{
    int deckSize;
    ArrayList<String> newDeck;
    Random rand;

    Dealer() 
    {
        deckSize = 52;
        newDeck = new CardDeck().getDeck();
        Collections.shuffle(newDeck);
        rand = new Random(42);
    }

    ArrayList dealHand() 
    {
        ArrayList<String> myHand = new ArrayList<>();
        int cardIndex;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++, deckSize--) 
        {
            cardIndex = rand.nextInt(deckSize);
            myHand.add(newDeck.get(cardIndex));
            newDeck.remove(cardIndex);// remove the card picked from the deck
        }
        return myHand;
    }
}
```

Here is the class that runs the program, Pokergame.java:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PokerGame 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Dealer dealer = new Dealer();

        ArrayList<String> PlayerOneHand = dealer.dealHand();
        ArrayList<String> PlayerTwoHand = dealer.dealHand();

        System.out.println("Player One's cards: " + PlayerOneHand);
        System.out.println("Player Two's cards: " + PlayerTwoHand);
        System.out.println();

        CompareHands hands = new CompareHands(PlayerOneHand, PlayerTwoHand);
        hands.compareHands(PlayerOneHand, PlayerTwoHand);
    }
}
```

And here is the error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CardDeck
>     at Dealer.(Dealer.java:14)    at PokerGame.main(PokerGame.java:9)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CardDeck     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 2 more

Comment: Did you add any imports?

Comment: Java would require a _classpath_ to find classes. Have you tried to pass a `-cp` argument to the `java` command?

Comment: Can you post your code? How do you run the classes, in which IDE?

Comment: No I didin't include any imports, I didn't add these classes to a package, I thought that the program would run since all the classes sit in the same directory.

Comment: I am running the classes through the command line, I wrote the code in sublime text

Comment: It would help if you added the code and error log to your question. I can't know the problem without seeing it.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: I'll add the error log

Comment: Can you add PokerGame.java as well?

Comment: Ok I added PokerGame.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you didn't compile the `CardDeck` class so it's not present on the `java` runtime classpath. Assuming that you are doing it manually with `javac` command you can recompile all the source files in the current directory with:

```
javac *.java
```

And then run the `PokerGame.main()` with:

```
java PokerGame
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you.

Comment: @DalanMiller try to learn a build tool like Maven or Gradle, it makes life so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells us that the java runtime can't find the `CardDeck.class` file at runtime. Make sure that it exists (compile all three java files) and that all three `class` files are in the same directory.

And take care the the file names exactly match the class names, namely: you need the files `CardDeck.java`, `Dealer.java` and `PokerGame.java`.